# How to get the first and last date of the current year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000, how can I get the first and last date of the current year?

Expected Output:

`01/01/2012` and `31/12/2012`

Answer (score 296, accepted):

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear,
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS EndOfYear
```

The above query gives a datetime value for midnight at the beginning of December 31. This is about 24 hours short of the last moment of the year. If you want to include time that might occur on December 31, then you should compare to the first of the next year, with a `<` comparison. Or you can compare to the last few milliseconds of the current year, but this still leaves a gap if you are using something other than DATETIME (such as DATETIME2):

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear,
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS LastDayOfYear,
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) AS FirstOfNextYear,
   DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS LastTimeOfYear
```

**Other Periods**

This approach has two nice aspects: good performance and it can easily be changed for other periods by replacing both occurrences of `yy` (=year) with a different string:

```
yy, yyyy    year
qq, q       quarter
mm, m       month
wk, ww      week
```

(Be careful of weeks: the starting day depends on server settings.)

**Tech Details**

This works by figuring out the number of years since 1900 with `DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE())` and then adding that to a date of zero = Jan 1, 1900. This can be changed to work for an arbitrary date by replacing the `GETDATE()` portion or an arbitrary year by replacing the `DATEDIFF(...)` function with "Year - 1900."

```
 SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, '20150301'), 0) AS StartOfYearForMarch2015,
   DATEADD(yy, 2015 - 1900, 0) AS StartOfYearFor2015
```

Comment: I know 0 represents 01/01/1900 - so `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` makes sense. But how about -1? `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)`, what is -1 represent? is it represent the day count since 01/01/1900 - which in this case -1 becomes 31/12/1899?

Comment: @Sam: the underlying representation for DateTime is based on a whole number equals one day. So yes, -1 represents a day before 1900-01-01 (0) which is 1899-12-31.

Answer (score 59):

Here's a fairly simple way;

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) AS 'First Day of Current Year';
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 12, 31) AS 'End of Current Year';
```

It's not sexy, but it works.

Comment: Only available starting from Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the current year using `DATEPART` function, from the current date obtained using `getUTCDate()`

```
SELECT 
    '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy, getUTCDate())), 
    '31/12/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy, getUTCDate()))
```

Comment: This outputs strings, not dates. If that's what you really need, yay, but if you can use either, keep the dates as dates, and don't use them as strings.

Comment: convert the strings to `DATETIME` using `CONVERT` function, the dates should be in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: I disagree, OP did not specify and the data formet set in sql server might return something like '2012-01-01 12:13:14' instead of '01/01/2012'

Comment: @RandyMorris, agree, the OP was asking if he can get `DATETIME` instead of string and obviously that may not match the expected output as per the question.

Comment: Why would you use an *ambiguous* date format (and the strings in your answer don't match the format in your comment)? `yyyyMMdd` is unambiguous.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the query in the response is to match the expected output as per the question. The comment about DATETIME is a response to OP's comment about getting date instead of string. The answer doesn't reflect this discussion.

Answer (score 10):

Another way: (Since SQL Server 2012)

```
SELECT
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) FirstDay,
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),12,31) LastDay
```

Answer (score 8):

simply write:-

```
select convert (date,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

start date of the year.

```
select convert (date,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()) + 1, -1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Every year has the 1 st as First date and 31 as the last date what you have to do is only attach the year to that day and month for example:-

```
 SELECT '01/01/'+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as [First Day],
 '12/31/'+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as [Last Day]
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true, as there are many [falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Comment: Could anyone give an example of when this will not work?

Comment: @slayernoah Depending on the localization settings of the server, I think this will sometimes generate an error.

Comment: Using this on SQL Server might not be safe depending on the regional settings. A safe version of this is to use the ISO format for dates that does always get correctly recognized regardless of the settings. This format for dates is yyyy-MM-dd. On top of that, the above returns strings, not real dates. The simplest way to do this kind of manipulation is datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) and datefromparts(year(getdate()), 12, 31).

Answer (score 3):

To get the first and the last day of the year, one can use the `CONCAT` function. The resulting value may be cast to any type.

```
CONCAT(YEAR(Getdate()),'-01-01') FirstOfYear,
CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'-12-31') LastOfYear
```

Comment: Year does not work for me but date_part works start_year_date := CONCAT(date_part('Y',start_date_p)::int::text,'-01-01')::date;

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to extract the current year then use concatenation like this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(year(now()), '-01-01') as start, -- fist day of current year
       CONCAT(year(now()), '-31-12') as end;   -- last day of current year
```

That gives you :   `start : 2020-01-01  and   end : 2020-31-12`  in date format.

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer instead of just code.

Comment: I added a short but concise description !

Comment: Returns strings, not DateTime objects, so not too efficient, if the result needs to be change into a date. This also looks like a duplicate of an earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

For start date of current year:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,-DATEPART(DY,GETDATE())+1,GETDATE())
```

For end date of current year:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

**The best way to get First Date and Last Date of a year Is**

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' AS DATE) FIRST_DATE
```

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '12' + '-' + '31' AS DATE) LAST_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one:

```
select convert(varchar(12),(DateAdd(month,(Month(getdate())-1) * -1, DateAdd(Day,(Day(getdate())-1) * -1,getdate()))),103) as StartYear,
       convert(varchar(12),DateAdd(month,12 - Month(getdate()), DateAdd(Day,(31 - Day(getdate())),getdate())),103) as EndYear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,-DATEPART(DY,GETDATE())+1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print Cast('1/1/' + cast(datepart(yyyy, getdate()) as nvarchar(4)) as date)
```

Comment: You should explain your code. Code dumps are often downvoted and may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like** you are interesting in performing an operation everything for a given year, if this is indeed the case, I would recommend to use the [YEAR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE YEAR(date_column) = '2012';
```

The same goes for [DAY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) and [MONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql). They are also available for MySQL/MariaDB variants and was introduced in SQL Server 2008 (so not for specific 2000).

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL) this can be done as follows

```
--beginning of year
select '01/01/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))

--end of year
select '12/31/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
```

**CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** - returns the sql server date at the time of execution of the query.

**YEAR** - gets the year part of the current time stamp.

**STR** , **LTRIM** - these two functions are applied so that we can convert this into a varchar that can be concatinated with our desired prefix (in this case it's either first date of the year or the last date of the year). For whatever reason the result generated by the **YEAR** function has prefixing spaces. To fix them we use the **LTRIM** function which is left trim.

Answer (score -1):

If it reaches the 1st of Jan you might it to be still last years date.

```
select
convert(date, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,  DATEadd(day, -1,getdate())), 0), 103 ) AS StartOfYear,
convert(date, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEDIFF(day, -1,getdate()))+1, -1), 103 )AS EndOfYear
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select to_date(substr(sysdate,1, 4) || '01/01'), to_date(substr(sysdate,1, 4) || '12/31') 
from dual
```

Comment: This is for PL-SQL, post says SQL Server 2000, so you have to use T-SQL. To_Date and Sysdate don't exist in T-SQL

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'01/01/%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'31/12/%Y')
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'NOW' is not a recognized function name.`

Comment: This answer uses MySQL functions (and casts dates to strings, which is one of my pet peeves).

Answer (score -4):

---Lalmuni Demos---

```
create table Users
(
userid int,date_of_birth date
)
```

---insert values---

```
insert into Users values(4,'9/10/1991')

select DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()),date_of_birth)) > getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Years, 
MONTH(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, date_of_birth, getdate()), date_of_birth))) - 1 as Months, 
DAY(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()), date_of_birth))) - 1 as Days,
from users
```