# SQL find out how many days into year date is

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to work out an annual figure as a proportion of the year based on the date - so if 400 is the annual figure, I want to divide this by 365 then multiply the result by however many days is equivalent to today's date (e.g. (400/365)*160)).

Is there a way of doing this with a SQL server select statement to avoid manually entering the 160 figure?

The 400 figure is coming from a standard field named HES.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you looking for the difference in days between 01/01/2015 and today's date? `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/01/15', GETDATE())`?

Comment: Of course that will malfunction as soon as 2016 rolls around. :) See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-first-and-last-date-of-current-year) for a way to get the first day of the current year.

Comment: Assuming that you don't call this code at exactly midnight, does the day we're currently in count or not (i.e. is the answer throughout January 1st "1" or "0")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `datepart(dayofyear, getdate())` - will return a number representing today's day of the year. See [MSDN DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: That looks like MySQL.

Comment: Need to change curdate() to getdate() for this to work in sql server.

Comment: You will need dayofyear instead of dayoftheyear. Other than that this looks like a great solution, so I removed mine that wasn't as elegant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is sql server and the other answer is using mysql I will post the sql server version.

```
select DATEPART(dayofyear, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

For your calculation, you might want to take leap years into account.  SQL Server has a convenient `datepart(dayofyear, . . )` functionality.  The complete solution would look like:

```
select datepart(dayofyear, dateadd(day, -1, cast(cast(year(getdate() + 1) as varchar(255)) + '0101' as date))) as daysinyear,
       datepart(dayofyear, getdate()) as currentday,
       datepart(dayofyear, getdate()) * 1.0 / datepart(dayofyear, dateadd(day, -1, cast(cast(year(getdate() + 1) as varchar(255)) + '0101' as date)))as daysinyear
```

Note that SQL Server does integer division, so to get a fraction, you need to convert to a decimal representation of some sort (`* 1.0` is just a simple way of doing this).