# How to get YTD data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
where (au.[DateTime]>= DATEADD(WK,-12,GETDATE()) AND au.[DateTime]< GETDATE())    
--gets everyday for the last 12 weeks
```

How can I modify to get every day for YTD?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-first-and-last-date-of-current-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where au.[DateTime] between DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
 AND DATEADD(ms,-2,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

This will get you the first day of the current year. A point i am not sure you need the And au.datetime ... since it is YTD it cannot have tomorrow data yet ? I tried -1 MS but for some reason it doesn't work. possible question.

Comment: Yes exactly. From the first of the month to yesterdau

Comment: I am sorry but is there way to get the a year from today... so instead of beginning of the year, it will be 8/12/2014?

Comment: select DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()) that will get it