# SQL - Modifying Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is the best way to take a date variable in SQL and set it to Beginning of Year and End of Year?

```
declare @calcDate date = '7/7/2016'
```

How do I get '1/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' using @calcDate?

Comment: please use the tags of the database engine that you are using. It even suggests you to do so when asking

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. What other tags should I add?

Comment: [sql] is the language, you could  be using SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql, etc. The answer will depend on which one you are using, so add the corresponding tags to your question

Comment: The first day of a year is always 1/1, and the last day is always 12/31. No need to "calculate" this.

Comment: I am currently running SQL Server 2012 if that helps

Comment: Already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-first-and-last-date-of-current-year

Comment: Thank you. That question didnt come up when I was searching for an existing solution. I apologize for the repetition.

Comment: @DaveKelly . . . There is a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @calcDate date = '7/7/2016'

SELECT
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@calcDate), 0) AS BeginningOfYear,
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@calcDate) + 1, -1) AS EndOfYear
```

Comment: This answer looks right why the down vote with no comment?

Comment: @DaveKelly Not my downvote, but this answer was posted when there were no tags about the RDBMS, so it could've been wrong for op. In this case, it wasn't

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(@calcdate), 1, 1) as soy,
       datefromparts(year(@calcdate), 12, 31) as eoy
```

Earlier versions of SQL Server require strange date arithmetic.  This function is available in SQL Server 2012+ (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)).

Comment: I got an error attempting to use DateFromParts. Does this function require a specific version of SQL Service 2012?

Comment: @inVad3r you might be using SQL Server management Studio 2012 on a database for a previous version

Comment: You would be correct. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there is no real "calculation" to be done here since the first day of the year is always 1/1 and the last day is always 12/31. We just need to append these to the year in question:

```
declare @calcDate date = '7/7/2016'
select cast(cast(year(@calcDate) as varchar(4)) + '0101' as date)
select cast(cast(year(@calcDate) as varchar(4)) + '1231' as date)
```

Result:

```
2016-01-01
2016-12-31
```

[`year`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) is available in SQL Server 2008 and above.