# SQL how to get information from The Start of some # of years ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have looked through a few posts but either there is too much information or I just don't quite understand what I am looking for.
eg: [How to get the first and last date of the current year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-date-of-the-current-year)

In a table I have sales orders for the last 20 years, all I want is to show the orders from January 1st of three years before until whatever the current date is.

```
   AND ShipDate >= (YEAR(ShipDate)-3)
```

Which doesn't work.

```
AND ShipDate >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE())
```

Which Shows exactly 2 years ago from whatever the current day is.

I want to be able to eventually create reports that show each year in the last three on their own but this is the first step and I am not doing well so far!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query used non-standard syntax). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Some examples would make it clear what you mean by "three years before".  I also added the SQL Server tag based on the code in the question.

Comment: Does `WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want is to show the orders from January 1st of three years before until whatever the current date is.

The best method in SQL Server is:

```
where shipdate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 3, 1, 1)
```

For any date in 2021, this returns all rows from 2021, 2020, 2019, and 2018.  If you don't want 2018, then use `- 2` rather than `- 3`.

This formulation has the option of being optimizer friendly (allowing the use of indexes and partitions, for example).  Two other common says to write this are not optimizer friendly:

```
where datediff(year, shipdate, getdate()) <= 3
where year(shipdate) >= year(getdate()) - 3
```

(Once again, the "3" might be "2" depending on what you really intend.)

Answer (score 0):

you were close:

```
AND YEAR(ShipDate) >= (YEAR(ShipDate)-3)
```

You were comparing a year to a date